# Do browser development tools provide an accurate visualization of the DOM?

Tags: html, dom, browser

Do browser development tools, e.g. Chrome Developer Tools simplify the "true" DOM in what they show to the developer? In other words, do browser development tools hide anything that would be considered part of the DOM by the browser?

From javascript.info/dom-nodes:

"Spaces at string start/end and space-only text nodes are usually hidden in tools Browser tools (to be covered soon) that work with DOM usually do not show spaces at the start/end of the text and empty text nodes (line-breaks) between tags. Developer tools save screen space this way."

I was wondering if anything else was omitted from the browser devtools, say, "to save space"

Comment: The browser development tools provide an accurate visualization of the DOM, hiding nothing that would be considered part of the DOM by the browser's DOM engine. Is there a reason you doubt the veracity of the browser devtools? That sounds like a more interesting question...

Comment: @HereticMonkey 

From https://javascript.info/dom-nodes:

"Spaces at string start/end and space-only text nodes are usually hidden in tools

Browser tools (to be covered soon) that work with DOM usually do not show spaces at the start/end of the text and empty text nodes (line-breaks) between tags.

Developer tools save screen space this way."

I was wondering if anything else was omitted from the browser devtools, say, "to save space"

Comment: I would add that explanation to your question as it is rather anemic right now. But even with that, it is a rather broad "list" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some developer tools will omit shadow-dom elements (at least, by default). For example:

```html
<input type="range">
```

This range input appears in Chrome dev tools like so:

[image]

What Chrome does not show is the [shadow-dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) elements of the range input, like the draggable thumb handle

However, if I toggle Chromes "show user agent shadow dom" dev feature, suddenly I can see the full DOM structure as the browser does:

[image]

This varies by browser though, Safari's devTools have shown shadow DOM elements by default for several years now